# Proof Phi is Irrational by using another Irrational Number

Tags: irrational-numbers, golden-ratio

It is known to mathematicians that [Phi (the golden ratio)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) is irrational number.

The value of Phi is $\frac{(1+\sqrt5)}2$. The task is to use another irrational number (not $\sqrt5$) to proof the irrationality of Phi.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for as using $5^{0.5}$ is a perfectly valid choice, and I presume other methods using other irrational numbers will use it in some way, albeit in a roundabout manner. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) might give you some ideas on what you might use.

Comment: *The task is to use another irrational number (not* $\sqrt5$ *)* --- You probably also want to exclude nonzero rational multiples of $\sqrt 5.$

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use any irrational numbers.
$\phi$ is a root of the polynomial $z^2 - z - 1$.  Using the Rational Root Theorem, it's easy to show that this has no rational roots.

If you really want to, you could change this into a proof that "uses" another
irrational number such as $1/\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can prove that there is no rational roots for $x^2+x-1$ using the rational root theorem. Since $\frac{1}{\varphi}$ and $-\varphi$ are roots to the equation, they are irrational, meaning that $\varphi$ itself is irrational.